# Mysql read string as datetime

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, sqldatetime

Hello I'm using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to populate a table in MySQL.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'
INTO TABLE myTestTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Everything is working peachy except that there is a datetime column in my data that is formatted without any delimiter between the date and time sections. Like so:

```
SomeDateColumn
20050101081946
```

When I read this in, MySQL replaces all the dates with dummy values. Is there a way to have MySQL read this in correctly straight from a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call `STR_TO_DATE` when you run `LOAD DATA`, and convert the text date to a bona fide date on the fly:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'
INTO TABLE myTestTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(
    col1, col2, @var1     -- list out all columns here
)

SET SomeDateColumn = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s');
```

Comment: A little reading of [manual pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) is always enlightening when solving a problem someone else may have come across :-)

Comment: @danblack It's actually rather hard to put together a query using just the docs, without knowing what it should look like.  Stack Overflow is helpful in this regard.

Comment: @danblack I have to back up Tim, the mysql docs are the least helpful documentation for beginners that I've seen (among major languages). This answer will help me understand the docs better. Thanks both!